# Морфологические термины

Tags: морфология, терминология

Какие термины, образованные от глаголов "стоять", "быть" и "идти", употребляются в морфологии?

Кажется, от *быть* - это бытийность (бытийный глагол, связка и т. д.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошедшее, настоящее, будущее время, имя существительное

Comment: Простите, а где здесь "стоять", "идти"?

Comment: Настоящее, прошедшее - прошёл (пройти <-- идти)

Comment: Да, спасибо; а "стоять"?

Comment: На-сто-ящ-ее (настоять <-- стоять)